# Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp() react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in firebase I just have the firebaseConfig file and I install the firebase **yarn add firebase** and

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import {firebaseConfig} from './assets/firebase/config'

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
```

adding this in app.js but I call this function

```
 const signInWithPhoneNumber = async ()=> {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(numberIs);
    console.log(confirmation)
    // setConfirm(confirmation);
  }
```

it gave me that error.
**Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp() react native**
I search alot but I can Find something which helps me

Comment: Are you getting this on iOS ?

Comment: no Android.......

Answer (score 1):

add these lines to your `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'
```

you would add these lines in the `dependencies`